# How to fix Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document error when parsing and A string literal was not closed error into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, x12

I am trying to extract the data from an XML file that has many duplicates and if I change the name it is not showing anything in the result,
I am not able to do it as I am using below code

```
DECLARE @xml_text VARCHAR(max), @i INT
SELECT @xml_text = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LIST>
  <ControlSegment EDIVERSION="5010" EDIMESSAGECODE="100" EDIMESSAGEFUNCTION="SM" TESTINDICATOR="P" ISACONTROLNUMBER="002125" GSCONTROLNUMBER="002125" SENDERQUALIFIER="14" SENDERID="NEWEFRIL00" RECEIVERQUALIFIER="02" RECEIVERID="C020C" />
  <ISA authorizationInformationQualifier="00" authorizationInformation="          " securityInformationQualifier="00" securityInformation="          " interchangeIDQualifier="14" interchangeSenderID="NEWEFRIL00" interchangeIDQualifier2="02" interchangeReceiverID="C020C" interchangeDate="2022-05-06T12:04:00" interchangeTime="12:04:00" repetitionSeparator="U" interchangeControlVersionNumber="00401" interchangeControlNumber="002125" acknowledgmentRequested="0" interchangeUsageIndicator="P" componentElementSeparator="|">
    <GS functionalIdentifierCode="SM" applicationSendersCode="006922827NWL1" applicationReceiversCode="RANGER" date="2022-05-06T12:04:00" time="12:04:00" groupControlNumber="002125" responsibleAgencyCode="X" versionReleaseIndustryIdentifierCode="004010">
      <ST transactionSetIdentifierCode="100" transactionSetControlNumber="002125">
        <B2 standardCarrierAlphaCode="RANGER" shipmentIdentificationNumber="64355525" weightUnitCode="L" shipmentMethodofPayment="PP" shipmentQualifier="L" totalEquipment="0.0" />
        <B2A transactionSetPurposeCode="01" applicationType="LT" />
        <L11 referenceIdentification="RANGER" referenceIdentificationQualifier="SCA" />
        <L11 referenceIdentification="Ryder" referenceIdentificationQualifier="ZZ" />
        <G62 dateQualifier="64" date="2022-05-05T14:20:00" timeQualifier="1" time="14:20:00" timeCode="ET" />
        <NTE noteReferenceCode="TRA" description="CFA 509-575-5500 transportation use up to date routing guide" />
        <loop0300>
          <S5 stopSequenceNumber="1" stopReasonCode="LD" weight="43069.2" weightUnitCode="L" numberofUnitsShipped="0" unitorBasisforMeasurementCode="PC" volume="2554.92" volumeUnitQualifier="E">
            <G62 dateQualifier="96" date="2022-06-03T16:30:00" timeQualifier="Y" time="16:30:00" timeCode="ED" />
            <PLD quantityofPalletsShipped="56" weight="0.0" />
            <NTE noteReferenceCode="TRA" description="CFA 509-575-5500 transportation use up to date routing guide" />
            <loop0310>
              <N1 entityIdentifierCode="SF" name="SAI Services" identificationCodeQualifier="93" identificationCode="2821">
                <N3 addressInformation="Gamers Colony" />
                <N4 cityName="SAI Services" stateorProvinceCode="IN" postalCode="500341" countryCode="HYD" />
                <G61 contactFunctionCode="SH" name="CONTACT CONTACT" communicationNumberQualifier="TE" communicationNumber="123-456-7890" />
              </N1>
            </loop0310>
            <loop0350>
              <OID referenceIdentification="2219274061" purchaseOrderNumber="Z45LQ" packagingFormCode="PC" quantity="0" weightUnitCode="L" weight="43069.2" volumeUnitQualifier="C" volume="2554.92">
                <loop0360>
                  <L5 ladingLineItemNumber="0.0" commodityCode="MISC" commodityCodeQualifier="N">
                    <AT8 weightQualifier="G" weightUnitCode="L" weight="43069.2" ladingQuantity="0.0" ladingQuantity2="0.0" volumeUnitQualifier="C" volume="2554.92" />
                    <loop0365>
                      <G61 contactFunctionCode="ZZ" name="ZZ">
                        <L11 referenceIdentification="Z45LQ" referenceIdentificationQualifier="DJ" />
                      </G61>
                    </loop0365>
                  </L5>
                </loop0360>
              </OID>
            </loop0350>
          </S5>
        </loop0300>
        <loop0300>
          <S5 stopSequenceNumber="2" stopReasonCode="UL" weight="43069.2" weightUnitCode="L" numberofUnitsShipped="0" unitorBasisforMeasurementCode="PC" volume="2554.92" volumeUnitQualifier="E">
            <G62 dateQualifier="97" date="2022-06-08T07:00:00" timeQualifier="Z" time="07:00:00" timeCode="PD" />
            <PLD quantityofPalletsShipped="56" weight="0.0" />
            <NTE noteReferenceCode="TRA" description="CFA 509-575-5500 transportation use up to date routing guide" />
            <loop0310>
              <N1 entityIdentifierCode="ST" name="ACE HDWE RETAIL SUPP CTR-9741" identificationCodeQualifier="93" identificationCode="17746">
                <N3 addressInformation="200 GRANT WAY" />
                <N4 cityName="GS Ground" stateorProvinceCode="WA" postalCode="500341" countryCode="HYD" />
              </N1>
            </loop0310>
            <loop0350>
              <OID referenceIdentification="2219274061" purchaseOrderNumber="Z45LQ" packagingFormCode="PC" quantity="0" weightUnitCode="L" weight="43069.2" volumeUnitQualifier="C" volume="2554.92">
                <loop0360>
                  <L5 ladingLineItemNumber="0.0" commodityCode="MISC" commodityCodeQualifier="N">
                    <AT8 weightQualifier="G" weightUnitCode="L" weight="43069.2" ladingQuantity="0.0" ladingQuantity2="0.0" volumeUnitQualifier="C" volume="2554.92" />
                    <loop0365>
                      <G61 contactFunctionCode="ZZ" name="ZZ">
                        <L11 referenceIdentification="Z45LQ" referenceIdentificationQualifier="DJ" />
                      </G61>
                    </loop0365>
                  </L5>
                </loop0360>
              </OID>
            </loop0350>
          </S5>
        </loop0300>
        <L3 weight="0" weightQualifier="G" freightRate="0" amountCharged="0" advances="0.0" prepaidAmount="0.0" volume="0" volumeUnitQualifier="E" ladingQuantity="0" weightUnitCode="L" declaredValue="0" rateValueQualifier2="PL" />
        <SE numberofIncludedSegments="32" transactionSetControlNumber="002125" />
      </ST>
      <GE numberofTransactionSetsIncluded="1" groupControlNumber="002125" />
    </GS>
    <IEA numberofIncludedFunctionalGroups="1" interchangeControlNumber="002125" />
  </ISA>
</LIST>';

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @i OUTPUT, @xml_text

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@i, '/LIST/',1)
--cross apply OPENXML(@i, '/LIST/ISA',2)
WITH 
(
EDIVERSION [varchar](50) '../@EDIVERSION',
EDIMESSAGECODE [varchar](50) '../@EDIMESSAGECODE',
EDIMESSAGEFUNCTION [varchar](50) '../@EDIMESSAGEFUNCTION',
TESTINDICATOR [varchar](50) '../@TESTINDICATOR',
ISACONTROLNUMBER [varchar](50) '../@ISACONTROLNUMBER',
GSCONTROLNUMBER [varchar](50) '../@GSCONTROLNUMBER',
SENDERQUALIFIER [varchar](50) '../@SENDERQUALIFIER',
RECEIVERQUALIFIER [varchar](50) '../@RECEIVERQUALIFIER',
RECEIVERID [varchar](50) '../@RECEIVERID',
authorizationInformationQualifier [varchar](50) '../@authorizationInformationQualifier',
authorizationInformation [varchar](50) '../@authorizationInformation',
securityInformationQualifier [varchar](50) '../@securityInformationQualifier',
securityInformation [varchar](50) '../@securityInformation',
interchangeIDQualifier [varchar](50) '../@interchangeIDQualifier',
interchangeSenderID [varchar](50) '../@interchangeSenderID',
interchangeIDQualifier [varchar](50) '../@interchangeIDQualifier',
interchangeReceiverID [varchar](50) '../@interchangeReceiverID',
interchangeDate [varchar](50) '../@interchangeDate',
repetitionSeparator [varchar](50) '../@repetitionSeparator',
interchangeControlVersionNumber [varchar](50) '../@interchangeControlVersionNumber',
interchangeControlNumber [varchar](50) '../@interchangeControlNumber',
acknowledgmentRequested [varchar](50) '../@acknowledgmentRequested',
interchangeUsageIndicator [varchar](50) '../@interchangeUsageIndicator',
componentElementSeparator [varchar](50) '../@componentElementSeparator',
functionalIdentifierCode [varchar](50) '../@functionalIdentifierCode',
applicationSendersCode [varchar](50) '../@applicationSendersCode',
[date] [varchar](50) '../@date',
[time] [varchar](50) '../@time',
groupControlNumber [varchar](50) '../@groupControlNumber',
responsibleAgencyCode [varchar](50) '../@responsibleAgencyCode',
versionReleaseIndustryIdentifierCode [varchar](50) '../@versionReleaseIndustryIdentifierCode',
transactionSetIdentifierCode [varchar](50) '@transactionSetIdentifierCode',
transactionSetControlNumber [varchar](50) '@transactionSetControlNumber',
standardCarrierAlphaCode [varchar](50) '@standardCarrierAlphaCode',
shipmentIdentificationNumber [varchar](50) '@shipmentIdentificationNumber',
weightUnitCode1 [varchar](50) '@weightUnitCode1',
shipmentMethodofPayment [varchar](50) '@shipmentMethodofPayment',
shipmentQualifier [varchar](50) '@shipmentQualifier',
totalEquipment [varchar](50) '@totalEquipment',
transactionSetPurposeCode [varchar](50) '@transactionSetPurposeCode',
applicationType [varchar](50) '@applicationType',
referenceIdentification1 [varchar](50) '@referenceIdentification1',
referenceIdentificationQualifier [varchar](50) '@referenceIdentificationQualifier',
dateQualifier1 [varchar](50) '@dateQualifier1',
[date3] [varchar](50) '@date3',
timeQualifier1 [varchar](50) '@timeQualifier1',
[time3] [varchar](50) '@time3',
noteReferenceCode [varchar](50) '@noteReferenceCode',
[description] [varchar](50) '@description',
stopSequenceNumber [varchar](50) '@stopSequenceNumber',
stopReasonCode [varchar](50) '@stopReasonCode',
weight1 [varchar](50) '@weight1',
weightUnitCode2 [varchar](50) '@weightUnitCode2',
numberofUnitsShipped [varchar](50) '@numberofUnitsShipped',
unitorBasisforMeasurementCode [varchar](50) '@unitorBasisforMeasurementCode',
volume3 [varchar](50) '@volume3',
volumeUnitQualifier4 [varchar](50) '@volumeUnitQualifier4',
dateQualifier2 [varchar](50) '@dateQualifier2',
[date1] [varchar](50) '@date1',
timeQualifier2 [varchar](50) '@timeQualifier2',
[time] [varchar](50) '@time',
timeCode [varchar](50) '@timeCode',
quantityofPalletsShipped [varchar](50) '@quantityofPalletsShipped',
weight2 [varchar](50) '@weight2',
noteReferenceCode1 [varchar](50) '@noteReferenceCode1',
description1 [varchar](50) '@description1',
entityIdentifierCode [varchar](50) '@entityIdentifierCode',
name [varchar](50) '@name',
identificationCodeQualifier [varchar](50) '@identificationCodeQualifier',
identificationCode [varchar](50) '@identificationCode',
addressInformation [varchar](50) '@addressInformation',
cityName [varchar](50) '@cityName',
stateorProvinceCode [varchar](50) '@stateorProvinceCode',
postalCode [varchar](50) '@postalCode',
countryCode [varchar](50) '@countryCode',
contactFunctionCode1 [varchar](50) '@contactFunctionCode1',
name2 [varchar](50) '@name2',
communicationNumberQualifier [varchar](50) '@communicationNumberQualifier',
communicationNumber [varchar](50) '@communicationNumber',
referenceIdentification2 [varchar](50) '@referenceIdentification2',
purchaseOrderNumber [varchar](50) '@purchaseOrderNumber',
packagingFormCode [varchar](50) '@packagingFormCode',
quantity [varchar](50) '@quantity',
weightUnitCode3 [varchar](50) '@weightUnitCode3',
weight3 [varchar](50) '@weight3',
volumeUnitQualifier [varchar](50) '@volumeUnitQualifier',
volume [varchar](50) '@volume',
ladingLineItemNumber [varchar](50) '@ladingLineItemNumber',
commodityCode [varchar](50) '@commodityCode',
commodityCodeQualifier [varchar](50) '@commodityCodeQualifier',
weightQualifier1 [varchar](50) '@weightQualifier1',
commodityCodeQualifier1 [varchar](50) '@commodityCodeQualifier1',
weight4 [varchar](50) '@weight4',
ladingQuantity7 [varchar](50) '@ladingQuantity7',
ladingQuantity2 [varchar](50) '@ladingQuantity2',
volumeUnitQualifier1 [varchar](50) '@volumeUnitQualifier1',
volume1 [varchar](50) '@volume1',
contactFunctionCode [varchar](50) '@contactFunctionCode',
name1 [varchar](50) '@name1',
referenceIdentification3 [varchar](50) '@referenceIdentification3',
referenceIdentificationQualifier1 [varchar](50) '@referenceIdentificationQualifier1',
weight5 [varchar](50) '@weight5',
weightQualifier [varchar](50) '@weightQualifier',
freightRate [varchar](50) '@freightRate',
amountCharged [varchar](50) '@amountCharged',
advances [varchar](50) '@advances',
prepaidAmount [varchar](50) '@prepaidAmount',
volume2 [varchar](50) '@volume2',
volumeUnitQualifier2 [varchar](50) '@volumeUnitQualifier2',
ladingQuantity4 [varchar](50) '@ladingQuantity4',
weightUnitCode4 [varchar](50) '@weightUnitCode4',
declaredValue [varchar](50) '@declaredValue',
rateValueQualifier2 [varchar](50) '@rateValueQualifier2',
numberofIncludedSegments [varchar](50) '@numberofIncludedSegments',
transactionSetControlNumber1 [varchar](50) '@transactionSetControlNumber1',
numberofTransactionSetsIncluded [varchar](50) '@numberofTransactionSetsIncluded',
groupControlNumber1 [varchar](50) '@groupControlNumber1',
numberofIncludedFunctionalGroups [varchar](50) '@numberofIncludedFunctionalGroups',
interchangeControlNumber [varchar](50) '@interchangeControlNumber'
)
```

This is how my result should look like when I don't want to use multiple cross apply but I am getting the same error

| EDIVERSION | EDIMESSAGECODE | EDIMESSAGEFUNCTION | TESTINDICATOR | ISACONTROLNUMBER | GSCONTROLNUMBER | SENDERID | RECEIVERQUALIFIER | RECEIVERID | authorizationInformationQualifier | authorizationInformation | securityInformationQualifier | securityInformation | interchangeIDQualifier | interchangeSenderID | interchangeIDQualifier2 | interchangeReceiverID | interchangeTime | repetitionSeparator | interchangeControlVersionNumber | interchangeControlNumber | acknowledgmentRequested | interchangeUsageIndicator | componentElementSeparator | functionalIdentifierCode | applicationSendersCode | date | time | groupControlNumber | responsibleAgencyCode | versionReleaseIndustryIdentifierCode | transactionSetIdentifierCode | transactionSetControlNumber | standardCarrierAlphaCode | shipmentIdentificationNumber | weightUnitCode | shipmentMethodofPayment | shipmentQualifier | totalEquipment | transactionSetPurposeCode | applicationType | referenceIdentification | referenceIdentificationQualifier | dateQualifier | date | timeQualifier | time | noteReferenceCode | description | stopSequenceNumber | stopReasonCode | weight | weightUnitCode | numberofUnitsShipped | unitorBasisforMeasurementCode | volume | volumeUnitQualifier | dateQualifier | date | timeQualifier | time | timeCode | quantityofPalletsShipped | weight | noteReferenceCode | description | entityIdentifierCode | name | identificationCodeQualifier | identificationCode | addressInformation | cityName | stateorProvinceCode | postalCode | countryCode | contactFunctionCode | name | communicationNumberQualifier | communicationNumber | referenceIdentification | purchaseOrderNumber | packagingFormCode | quantity | weightUnitCode | weight | volumeUnitQualifier | volume | ladingLineItemNumber | commodityCode | commodityCodeQualifier | weightQualifier | commodityCodeQualifier | weight | ladingQuantity | ladingQuantity2 | volumeUnitQualifier | volume | contactFunctionCode | name | referenceIdentification | referenceIdentificationQualifier | weight | weightQualifier | freightRate | amountCharged | advances | prepaidAmount | volume | volumeUnitQualifier | ladingQuantity | weightUnitCode | declaredValue | rateValueQualifier2 | numberofIncludedSegments | transactionSetControlNumber | numberofTransactionSetsIncluded | groupControlNumber | numberofIncludedFunctionalGroups | interchangeControlNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5010 | 204 | SM | P | 19708 | 19708 | 14 | 02 | C020C | 00 |  | 00 |  | 14 | NEWEFRIL00 | 02 | C020C | 2022-05-06T12:04:00 | U | 00401 | 19708 | 0 | P | :------------------------ | SM | 006922827NWL1 | 2022-05-06T12:04:00 | 12:04:00 | 19708 | X | 004010 | 204 | 19708 | XPOG | 64355525 | L | PP | L | 0.0 | 01 | LT | Ryder | ZZ | 64 | 2022-05-05T14:20:00 | 1 | 14:20:00 | TRA | CFA 509-575-5500 transportation use up to date routing guide | 1 | LD | 43069.2 | L | 0 | PC | 2554.92 | E | 64 | 2022-05-05T14:20:00 | 1 | 14:20:00 | ET | 56 | 0.0 | TRA | CFA 509-575-5500 transportation use up to date routing guide | SF | FISHERS | 93 | 2821 | 200 GRANT WAY | FISHERS | IN | 46037 | USA | SH | CONTACT CONTACT | TE | 123-456-7890 | 2219274061 | Z45LQ | PC | 0 | L | 43069.2 | C | 2554.92 | 0.0 | MISC | N | G | L | 43069.2 | 0.0 | 0.0 | C | 2554.92 | ZZ | ZZ | Z45LQ | DJ | 0 | G | 0 | 0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0 | E | 0 | L | 0 | PL | 32 | 19708 | 1 | 19708 | 1 | 19708 |
| 5010 | 204 | SM | P | 19708 | 19708 | 14 | 02 | C020C | 00 |  | 00 |  | 14 | NEWEFRIL00 | 02 | C020C | 2022-05-06T12:04:00 | U | 00401 | 19708 | 0 | P | :------------------------ | SM | 006922827NWL1 | 2022-05-06T12:04:00 | 12:04:00 | 19708 | X | 004010 | 204 | 19708 | XPOG | 64355525 | L | PP | L | 0.0 | 01 | LT | Ryder | ZZ | 64 | 2022-05-05T14:20:00 | 1 | 14:20:00 | TRA | CFA 509-575-5500 transportation use up to date routing guide | 1 | LD | 43069.2 | L | 0 | PC | 2554.92 | E | 64 | 2022-05-05T14:20:00 | 1 | 14:20:00 | ET | 56 | 0.0 | TRA | CFA 509-575-5500 transportation use up to date routing guide | SF | FISHERS | 93 | 2821 | 200 GRANT WAY | MOXEE CITY | WA | 98936 | USA | SH | CONTACT CONTACT | TE | 123-456-7890 | 2219274061 | Z45LQ | PC | 0 | L | 43069.2 | C | 2554.92 | 0.0 | MISC | N | G | L | 43069.2 | 0.0 | 0.0 | C | 2554.92 | ZZ | ZZ | Z45LQ | DJ | 0 | G | 0 | 0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0 | E | 0 | L | 0 | PL | 32 | 19708 | 1 | 19708 | 1 | 19708 |
| 5010 | 204 | SM | P | 19708 | 19708 | 14 | 02 | C020C | 00 |  | 00 |  | 14 | NEWEFRIL00 | 02 | C020C | 2022-05-06T12:04:00 | U | 00401 | 19708 | 0 | P | :------------------------ | SM | 006922827NWL1 | 2022-05-06T12:04:00 | 12:04:00 | 19708 | X | 004010 | 204 | 19708 | XPOG | 64355525 | L | PP | L | 0.0 | 01 | LT | Ryder | ZZ | 64 | 2022-05-05T14:20:00 | 1 | 14:20:00 | TRA | CFA 509-575-5500 transportation use up to date routing guide | 1 | LD | 43069.2 | L | 0 | PC | 2554.92 | E | 64 | 2022-05-05T14:20:00 | 1 | 14:20:00 | ET | 56 | 0.0 | TRA | CFA 509-575-5500 transportation use up to date routing guide | SF | FISHERS | 93 | 2821 | 9999 E 121ST STREET | FISHERS | IN | 46037 | USA | SH | CONTACT CONTACT | TE | 123-456-7890 | 2219274061 | Z45LQ | PC | 0 | L | 43069.2 | C | 2554.92 | 0.0 | MISC | N | G | L | 43069.2 | 0.0 | 0.0 | C | 2554.92 | ZZ | ZZ | Z45LQ | DJ | 0 | G | 0 | 0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0 | E | 0 | L | 0 | PL | 32 | 19708 | 1 | 19708 | 1 | 19708 |

If there is any others please do suggest.

Comment: I highly recommend a [mre] with emphasis in *minimal* i.e. the bare minimum example and data which illustrates the issue.

Comment: `OPENXML` is the old, pre-2005 way of doing things. Use the XML methods instead (`.nodes()`, `.query()`, `.value()`), then no `preparedocument` calls are needed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, that is the other solution right in which we have to use multiple **cross apply** right. but that will take too much time to execute the query because we are using multiple cross apply. if I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: I have no idea if you need zero, one or multiple `CROSS APPLY`s, your markup is far too big and messy for me to bother with. All I'm saying is that `OPENXML` doesn't allow you to do anything you can't also do with the XML methods, while being less convenient. It will certainly not be the case that `OPENXML` is faster just because the query doesn't have `CROSS APPLY` somewhere; XML querying is always rather slow anyway.

Comment: Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL 
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.
Also, OPENXML() cannot take advantage of XML indexes as XQuery methods can.